# AOSP user variant ROM for pixels

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-source, google-pixel

Is anyone aware on how to create AOSP ROMs in user variant. I have done that in userdebug mode, but in user variant post flashing of ROM, it is getting stuck in boot loop
What all could be the reason for it??
I am following the steps which are there in official Android sites

I have tried the steps mentioned here -
https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building

But it is not working for me in user variant mode

Comment: Share more details about your setup for debugging. Please take a look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask